# Rails - update flash using an ajax post action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an action that calls a javascript file which contains an ajax method like this one:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<%= some_action(model) %>",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'something': true },
    success: function(received_data) { 
        // Do something with received_data 
        $('#notice').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/flash_messages', flash: flash).html_safe %>");
    }
});
```

The "some_action" tries to put some info into flash[:success], and I want to get it in the success function so that I can pass it to the render.

I have already tried the flash.now[:sucess], but nothing. It seems that it is only possible to do this if I write in the flash hash from the action that calls this javascript file - but I don't want this since "some_action" will generate dynamic content.

Is that something possible to to?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send js request instead of json request .

and then in your "some_action.js.haml" file you can write

```
$('#notice').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'layouts/flash_messages', flash: flash).html_safe %>");
```

what's happening here is that your javascript file is not getting refreshed hence content of html is not changing .